# Return all rows from both queries/tables with left join

Tags: php, sql

I have two subqueries on which I am doing a join, first one returns following data:

```
array (size=110)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'scans' => string '7' (length=1)
      'bonus_points' => string '0' (length=1)
      'date' => string '2017-06-13' (length=10)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'scans' => string '20' (length=2)
      'bonus_points' => string '0' (length=1)
      'date' => string '2017-06-14' (length=10)
```

second one:

```
array (size=21)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'redeems' => string '1' (length=1)
      'date' => string '2017-06-14' (length=10)
```

If I do a left join on those two like so:

```
LEFT JOIN query2 ON query2.date=query1.date;
```

I get the following:

```
array (size=110)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      'scans' => string '7' (length=1)
      'bonus_points' => string '0' (length=1)
      'date' => null
      'redeems' => null
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      'scans' => string '20' (length=2)
      'bonus_points' => string '0' (length=1)
      'date' => string '2017-06-14' (length=10)
      'redeems' => string '1' (length=1)
```

Everything is as I want it to be, except that the left query doesn't always have the same dates as the right query and then the result is `'date' => null`.

How can I keep the data from both queries?

Comment: @splash58 left outer does the same as only left, right and full outer return only the rows from the second table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the `date` column from the left table, not from the right (joined) one.

Comment: Actually this works, thank you, such a simple solution